# Proving nonexistence of a $1-1 $ continuous correspondence between $\mathbb{S^1}$ and $[0,1]$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I want to prove that there not exist a one to one countinuous correspondence between $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $[0,1]$,

but I don't have idea about how I can do this...

Comment: There are many bijections between $\Bbb S^1$ and $[0,1]$. Why the tag topology?

Comment: Maybe the statement you were thinking about is "there is no homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $[0,1]$?" (A homeomorphism being a continuous bijection with continuous inverse)

Comment: I'm ashamed, forget a hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what background you have in topology, but here is a hint on a "standard" way to do it: continuous surjective maps preserve connectedness, *ie* if $f : X \to Y$ is continuous and surjective, $X$ connected $\implies Y$ connected (do you see why this is true?)

Then, you can try and use this to derive a contradiction :). Let me know if you want me to detail this more

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however I do not see how connectedness can be useful to me. Is [0,1] not already connected because it is an interval?

Comment: It is. However, what happens if you, say, remove a point from $\mathbb{S}^1$. Is it still connected? What about $[0,1]$?

Comment: ohhhh It is true! Now, I can see it. Thank you so much!